# Why do I get ".push not a function"?

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

What's wrong with my code?

```js
function longestConsec(strarr, k) {
  var currentLongest = "";
  var counter = 0;
  var outPut = [];

  if(strarr.length === 0 || k > strarr.length || k <= 0){
    return "";
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < strarr.length; i++){
    if(strarr[i] > currentLongest){
      currentLongest = strarr[i];
    }
  }
  while(currentLongest !== strarr[counter]){
    counter = counter + 1
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < k; j ++){
    outPut = outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);
  }

  outPut = outPut.join("");

   return outPut;
}
```

I keep on getting "outPut.push is not a function".

Comment: array.push returns the length of the array after pushing ... after the first push, `outPut` is now a NUMBER not an ARRAY - simply change `outPut = outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);` to `outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);`

Comment: Also, k <= 0 is possibly k =< 0

Comment: because someone did post a "code only" answer, they deleted it rather than explain it, thought they may want to explain it, so why post an answer as well :p

Comment: @Vini - no, not at all

Comment: You don't need to reassign output when you push an element to the array. Just use .push();

Comment: Read about [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Why the name "`outPut`"? Is "`output`" reserved?

Answer (score 15):

Array push functions returns the length of the array after pushing.

So, in your code

```
outPut = outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);
```

outPut is now a number, not an array, so the second time through the loop, outPut no longer has a push method.

A simple solution is to change that line to

```
outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new
>   length of the array.

And you have this line:

```
outPut = outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);
```

You're adding an element to `outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);` and then reassigning `outPush` to the length of the array.

You should only call the `push` method on the array and a new element will be added:

```
for (var j = 0; j < k; j ++){
    outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.push() returns the length of that particular array. In your code, you assign a number to `outPut`. Now when the loop runs for the second time, `outPut` is no more an array but a number, hence you get the error.

You check it by logging `outPut` to the console. You will see that

```
for (var j = 0; j < k; j ++){
    outPut = outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);
    console.log(outPut);
}
```

It will show:

```
 1
  VM696:18 Uncaught TypeError: outPut.push is not a function
    at longestConsec (<anonymous>:18:21)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

All you need to do is change it to:

```
for (var j = 0; j < k; j ++){
    outPut.push(strarr[counter + j]);
}
```