# I am just wondering what is going wrong with my code of adding 2 arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I did try this

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var sum = [];
for (var i = 0; arr1[i] < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; arr2[j] < arr2.length; j++) {
    sum = sum.push(arr1[i] + arr2[j]);
  }
}

console.log(sum);
```

Found the right solution, However trying to understand where my code is going wrong.  It says sum is not defined.

Do let me know or any ref would also do good.
Thanks Folks

Comment: `sum = sum.push(arr1[i] + arr2[j]);` - the `push()` method returns the new *length* of the array. Doesn't return an array.

Comment: You overwrite `sum` with the return value of `sum.push()`, push alters the array, it does not return a new array.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: You don't need to do `sum = sum.push()`.

`sum.push()` on its own will add the item to the array, you don't need to set the variable.

Comment: Dupe of [Why do I get “.push not a function”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394192/why-do-i-get-push-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuning you want a new array with sum of each value at same index, you could take a single loop and add the values at same index.

[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, and has nothing to do with the pushed value.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    sum = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    sum.push(arr1[i] + arr2[i]);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

Array.push does not return a new array. It modifies the given array. So basically you just need to change:

```
 sum = sum.push(arr1[i] + arr2[j]);
```

To:

```
sum.push(arr1[i] + arr2[j]); //without the assignment
```

And it should work!

Answer (score 0):

`Array.push` is mutating the original array. [And it will return length of updated array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value). so while call on `2` nd time the `sum` is number not array .Thats why you got error

so should not reassign `sum = sum.push`

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var sum = [];
for (var i = 0; arr1[i] < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; arr2[j] < arr2.length; j++) {
    sum.push(arr1[i] + arr2[j]);
  }
}

console.log(sum);
```