# Why am I getting .slice is not a function?

Tags: javascript

I know that `.slice()` can only work on arrays and strings. I'm calling `.slice()` on an array and I am still getting that error. Here is my code:

```js
var subsets = function(nums) {
    let subsets = [];
    subsets.push([]);
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        let currentNumber = nums[i];
        for(let j = 0; j < subsets.length; j++) {
            let currentSubset = subsets[j].slice(0);
            let set1 = currentSubset.push(currentNumber);
            subsets.push(set1)
            
        }
    }
    return subsets;
};
```

Now on the other hand, this works fine if I insert it into the for loop.

```js
const set1 = subsets[j].slice(0); // clone the permutation
set1.push(currentNumber);
subsets.push(set1);
```

Comment: `splice` or `slice`?

Comment: .slice is what I meant

Comment: Update the code to show how you call it

Comment: Because of subsets[j] is not an array please check it

Comment: you are mutating `subsets` array within its for loop. That is a bad idea

Comment: I call the code like this subsets([1,2,3]). Also if I do subsets[j], that should = [].

Comment: But it isn't--log (or inspect at a breakpoint) `subsets` inside the `j` loop.

Comment: I edited the code to show a solution that works, I don't get what's different about the two.

Comment: It's *very* different: look at the docs for `push`. What does it return?

Comment: The error occurs for currentSubset = subsets[j].slice(0), but works just fine for set1 = subsets[j].slice(0);

Comment: That isn't where the error is. The difference is what you're pushing.

Comment: Interesting you're right, but the error message oddly enough said .slice is not a function on the slice line. thanks for the help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394192/why-do-i-get-push-not-a-function/48394287#48394287

Comment: @FirstLast It's not odd; the error is there because of what you push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let set1 = currentSubset.push(currentNumber);
subsets.push(set1)
```

Here `currentSubset.push()` will return lenth of new array and which you store in `subsets` array. And that you have declared array of array.
So in next iteration `subsets[1]` will be length of array which you stored from `set1` not an array.
So I guess you missed some logic over there.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.push` returns a number, the new length of the array.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value):

> ### Return value
>
> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

When you `subsets.push(set1)`, you push a number, and numbers don't have `.slice`.

You should do `subsets.push(currentSubset)` instead.